# How can we switch columns when first is Null

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

How can we direct the command to second column when first one is NULL for extracting the data, and the second column is Joined with another table through Join Command.

```
    Select
competitions.name as "Competition",
to_char(to_date(date,'DY Mon DD YYYY'),'D.MM.YYYY') as "Date Aired",
case when home_team.name Is null then to_char(to_date(date,'DY Mon DD YYYY'),'MM-DD')||' '||video_jobs.event else
to_char(to_date(date,'DY Mon DD YYYY'),'MM-DD')||' '||Away_team.name||' '||'@'||' '||home_team.name end as "Title",
min(case when new_status_id = 19 then to_char(timestamp,'DD.MM.YY') end) as "Analysis Start date",
min(case when new_status_id = 13 then to_char(timestamp,'DD.MM.YY') end) as "Analysis Complete",
min(case when new_status_id = 9 then to_char(timestamp,'DD.MM.YY') end) as "Upload complete"

from video_jobs

Join job_statuses on video_jobs.status_id = job_statuses.id
join teams as Home_team on video_jobs.home_team_id = home_team.id
join teams as Away_team on video_jobs.away_team_id = Away_team.id
Join competitions on video_jobs.competition_id = competitions.id
Join video_job_status_history on video_jobs.id = video_job_status_history.video_job_id

Where video_jobs.id = 163887 --and video_jobs.market_id=9 
-- and video_jobs.status_id != 32

group by
video_jobs.id,
competitions.name,
home_team.name,
```

Comment: Are you using an ETL tool? If so, which one? If not, can you post the SQL you have so far? Thanks

Comment: Are you using mysql or postgresql? They're not the same thing. Please only add tags that actually apply to your question instead of just randomly grabbing things that look similar. Tags here have specific definitions (which you can see in the description that appears when you're typing it in, or via the tag's tagwiki here). Using the proper tags helps it get before the people who can best help you, and properly classifies it for future users who are searching for help here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is far from clear, but I believe you are looking for the `coalesce` function, which is supported by both [Postgres](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN12663) and [MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT COALESCE(t1.column1, t2.column2) AS unified_column
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN table2 AS t2 USING (joincolumn)
```